error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

php: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I experienced an error like the picture above, when uploading the Laravel deploy project to Vercel, what should I do if it's like this? please help
I hope to find a way out, thank you
